# How to create unique constraint in Elasticsearch database?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch as a document database and each record I create has a guid id that the system uses for the record id. Business people want to offer a feature to let the user have their own auto file name convention based on date and how many records were created so far this day/month.

What I need is to prevent duplicate user file names. Is there a way to setup an indexed field to be unique? Like a sql unique constraint?

Comment: i believe that the only unique constrain applies to the `_id` field

Comment: Your question is wrong, elasticsearch is not a data-base but a search engine based on Apache Lucene, which not support such features. Also keep in mind that ES is "near" realtime.

Comment: _Document oriented databases tend not to do this, and Elasticsearch is no different._ Take a look at [Elasticsearch as a NoSQL Database](https://www.elastic.co/es/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'd need to use the field that is supposed to be unique as id for your documents. By default a new document with existing id would override the existing document with same id, but you can switch to `op_type=create` in order to get back an error if a document with same id already exists.

There's no way to have the same behaviour with arbitrary fields though, only the [`_id`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) field works that way. I would probably consider handling this logic in the application layer instead of within elasticsearch.

Comment: I would suggest having a separate collection/type that is simply a pointer to the original document... this way your originals will still have the uuid, and you can even the unique name as a field in the original, the separate type/document will act as a unique index to the original.

Answer (score 2):

One solution will be to use  `uniqueId` field value for specifying document ID and use `op_type=create` while storing the documents in ES. With this you can make sure your `uniqueId` field will have unique value and will not be overridden by another same valued document.

For this, the elasticsearch document says:

> The index operation also accepts an op_type that can be used to force a create operation, allowing for "put-if-absent" behavior. When create is used, the index operation will fail if a document by that id already exists in the index.

Here is an example of using the op_type parameter:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/es_index/es_type/unique_a?op_type=create' -d  '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "uniqueId" : "unique_a"
}'
```

If you run the above request it is ok, but running it the next time will give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the _id in the column you want to have unique contraint on.
Here is the sample river that uses postgresql. Yo can change the Database Driver/DB-URL according to your usage.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/simple_jdbc_river/_meta -d "{\"type\":\"jdbc\",\"jdbc\":{\"strategy\":\"simple\",\"poll\":\"1s\",\"driver\":\"org.postgresql.Driver\",\"url\":\"jdbc:postgresql://DB-URL/DB-INSTANCE\",\"user\":\"USERNAME\",\"password\":\"PASSWORD\",\"sql\":\"select t.id as _id,t.name from topic as t \",\"digesting\" : true},\"index\":{\"index\":\"jdbc\",\"type\":\"topic_jdbc_river1\"}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

So far as to *ES 7.5*, there is no such extra "constraint" to ensure uniqueness using a custom field in the mapping.

But you still can walk around it via your own application UUID, which could be used directly **explicitly** as the [`_id`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) (which is unique implictly) to achieve your goals.

```
PUT <your_index_name>/_doc/<your_app_uuid>
{
  "a_field": "a_value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to generate the string you store in a field that should be unique by integrating an auto-incrementing integer. This way you ensure from the start that your field values are unique.

You would put your file name together like this:

```
<current day/month>_<auto-incremented integer>
```

Auto-incrementing integers are not supported by Elasticsearch per se but you could mimic them using this [approach](http://blogs.perl.org/users/clinton_gormley/2011/10/elasticsearchsequence---a-blazing-fast-ticket-server.html). If you happen to use node.js you can use the [es-sequence](https://github.com/analog-nico/es-sequence) module.