# How to prevent duplicate document insertion in elastic search index?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Is there unique constraints, we can put on elastic search index to prevent duplicate insertion?

I have been exploring this for quite long time but i am not able to find it.

In my case, duplicate documents are being inserted in elastic search index with different _id.

For example - In below detail, movie index contains two records with different _ids.

```
{
   "_index": "movies",
   "_type": "movie",
   "_id": "AV4jhLAYQqa7xxY9fFkM",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source":{"movieName":"The War"}
},
{
  "_index": "movies",
  "_type": "movie",
  "_id": "AV4jjQPbfc86ZOjMT9mQ",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source":{"movieName":"The War"}
},
```

Please help anyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create unique constraint in Elasticsearch database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461269/how-to-create-unique-constraint-in-elasticsearch-database)

Comment: Looks like the same question as the previous one really.

Comment: @SrmHitter9062 if you just don't want to have duplicate documents you may consider creating `_id` value yourself, so same document will be just updated when inserted twice. Anyways, `_id` is the solution proposed in the question mentioned above.

Comment: @Nikolay  thanks ,that worked but still it updates the same document.can we prevent that updation also if anything there ?

Comment: @SrmHitter9062 As far as I understood from the aforementioned question it is possible to return an error in case of same _id already existing, but nothing more.