# Remove duplicate records in document (Elasticsearch)

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch

I am writing my own application for integration between Elasticsearch and SQL Server and I am sending all the data from selected table in SQL Server to Elasticsearch, but I have one problem.

If I set in my application that will hook every minute to that table, it will store those records again every minute in Elasticsearch. That makes a lot of duplicate records in Elasticsearch document.

Is there a query in Elasticsearch that can check if there are any duplicate records (duplicate in every property) and remove that duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but not via a special query, rather in changing the way you index documents.

### How can I ensure unique documents?

This question has probably been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461269/how-to-create-unique-constraint-in-elasticsearch-database/21463697#21463697), and the point is to explicitly define the [`_id`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/mapping-id-field.html) of the inserted document.

To achieve what you want you may try to compute hash of the entire json before sending it to Elasticsearch and use it as `_id`. (Make sure that the json is serialized to string in stable fashion, like [`sort_keys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) does in python.)

If you have some other unique identifier it may be better to use it instead of data hash.

The existing index unfortunately should be reindexed (with `_id`s computed in the new fashion).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have used this principle. I am computing a hash based on merged strings of entire row record which is resulting in unique hash. If that hash exists in document records it will be ignored for inserting values in document. This is a good method to do this since I can't know if table will have unique values by itself, like ID or something else.

I was hoping that Elasticsearch would have something integrated, but this is working as well. Thanks for a suggestion.