# How to avoid same object persistence multiple times elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am persisting data through elasticsearch and even though the data is persisted multiple times, it will be stored with auto-generated different string id values. I want multiple entries of the same data to be avoided from being persistence by making the email field as the primary key. How could I achieve this in elasticsearch

```
{
  "email":"abc@pe.com",
  "name": "abc"
}

return client.prepareIndex(Constants.INDEX_NAME, Constants.TYPE)
            .setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
                .field("email", email)
                .field("name", name)
            .endObject())
            .get();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461269/how-to-create-unique-constraint-in-elasticsearch-database
You need to set then your email as the _id Field.

Comment: If you need to keep your id, consider upsert by querry the email field.