# Is there any way to generate unique Long Id in sequence in elasticsearch java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a unique long id. I cannot use @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) as there is no database. I wanted to know if elasticsearch provides any annotations to create int/long unique id.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Document(indexName = "province", type = "pdf")
public class Pdf implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

   //getter and setters
   // contructor with and without fields 
}
```

Comment: Can you use `java.util.UUID` instead?

Comment: @nabster no I am looking for something which will generate id in sequence and unique

Comment: I would check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461269/how-to-create-unique-constraint-in-elasticsearch-database)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461269/how-to-create-unique-constraint-in-elasticsearch-database)question on SO. 
Since Elasticsearch is not your typical RDBMS, I don't believe the concept of auto-incremented unique primary keys applies here. You would need to handle "uniqueness" logic at your application level for each document entry upon POST.

Comment: ES index is a combination of 1 to many field. If you don't provide one, then ES will generate a random id for it, not in sequence.