# Unique constraint on field in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

It is possible to create unique constraint in Spring Data Elasticsearch which is equal to `@Column(unique = true)` in RDBMS?

Unfortunately, `@Field` annotation does not have `Unique` param.
Perhaps I could use `@Id` but what if there are other fields like username, email, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their is no unique constraint in Elasticsearch.
You can use your field as an _id like explained in this post :
[How to create unique constraint in Elasticsearch database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461269/how-to-create-unique-constraint-in-elasticsearch-database)

Or you'll have to create a validator by yourself to test if the value exist with some term query.

**Addition:** Although the `op_type` parameter sent to Elasticsearch would provide this feature, there is currently no support for this flag in Spring Data Elasticsearch. There is [an issue in Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-368) which you could upvote.