# How to enforce uniqueness on a field in Elasticsearch to avoid duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Foo, String> {
    Foo findByName(String name);
}
```

How to enforce uniqueness on a field in Elasticsearch to avoid duplicates, I want name to be unique in Foo. Is there a way to enforce this using FieldType metadata

Comment: foo is your index or fieldname??

Comment: foo is my index

Comment: name is an attribute within Foo

Comment: so you want to make sure all the values in `name` field of your `foo` index to be unique ??

Comment: yes and just throw an error if its not before inserting the document, how should I enforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniqueness of a field in Elasticsearch is guaranteed only for id fields and if you want the error if you try to update the same id value, you can use the [op_type=create](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-query-params) in your index-API.

There are several posts on Elastic's discuss and stackoverflow confirming the same behavior.

few good posts which you can follow for further understanding like [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/uniqueness-constraint/8615/2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21463697/4039431) and [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/handling-unique-field-other-than-the-id/96034)